# Hexadecimal to base64 conversion

Tags: hex, base64

I'm currently working on an hex->base64 converter. How am I suppsoed to handle an odd number of hex-digits? What I did until now is that every hex-digit is an 4-bit number, so 2 hex-digits are 1 byte. If I encounter an odd number of hex-digits do I simply fill the rest of the uncomplete byte with 0? Or am I supposed to return an error?

Comment: We have no context here - who is in charge of the requirements? What is this actually *for*? I'd expect it to normally be an error, but it really depends on the context.

Comment: http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1/ working on this challenge

Comment: Well if you expect 2 hex digits for a byte but don't get them the input is not valid and not fixable (whats FFF ? 0FFF or FFF0?) - throw an exception.

Comment: Yes - for that, I'd say it's entirely reasonable to fail if the number of nybbles is odd.

Answer (score 4):

I completed this challenge in C. I use a loop to remove leading zeroes, or 'A's in this case.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char* hex_to_base64(char *hex, int size)
{
    int size64 = (size * 2) / 3.0;
    size64 += 1;
    char *base64 = calloc(size64, 1);
    size64 -= 1;
    for (int i = size-1; i>= 0; i-=3, size64-=2) {
        base64[size64] |= hex[i];
        if (i > 0) {
            base64[size64] |= ((hex[i - 1] << 4) & 0x3F); //0x3F is 00111111
            base64[size64 - 1] |= (hex[i - 1] >> 2);
        }
        if (i > 1) {
            base64[size64 - 1] |= ((hex[i - 2] << 2));
        }
    }
    return base64;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    //49276D206B696C6C696E6720796F757220627261696E206C696B65206120706F69736F6E6F7573206D757368726F6F6D
    char input[] = { 4, 9, 2, 7, 6, 13, 2, 0, 6, 11, 6, 9, 6, 12, 6, 12, 6, 9, 6, 14, 6, 7, 2, 0, 7, 9, 6, 15, 7, 5, 7, 2, 2, 0, 6, 2, 7, 
        2, 6, 1, 6, 9, 6, 14, 2, 0, 6, 12, 6, 9, 6, 11, 6, 5, 2, 0, 6, 1, 2, 0, 7, 0, 6, 15, 6, 9, 7, 3, 6, 15, 6, 14, 6, 15, 7, 5, 7, 3, 
        2, 0, 6, 13, 7, 5, 7, 3, 6, 8, 7, 2, 6, 15, 6, 15, 6, 13 };
    char *output;
    int outputsize = ((sizeof(input)* 2) / 3.0) + 1;
    char *text = calloc(outputsize + 1, 1);
    char *formatted;
    output = hex_to_base64(input, sizeof(input));
    for (i = outputsize-1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (output[i] < 26) {
            text[i] = output[i] + 65;
        }
        else if (output[i] < 52) {
            text[i] = output[i] + 97 - 26;
        }
        else if (output[i] < 62) {
            text[i] = output[i] + 48 - 52;
        }
        else if (output[i] == 62) {
            text[i] = '+';
        }
        else if (output[i] == 63) {
            text[i] = '/';
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    formatted = text;
    while (text[i++] == 'A') {
        formatted++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", formatted);
    free(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is int size64 supposed to be a signed 64 bit variable? On the CPU I'm working with, int is 32 bits.
I declare my variables like uint32_t etc. to avoid confusion.

Comment: This did not work for me at all. In this time I could have written it myself, what a bummer.

Answer (score 3):

Found this question working on cryptopals challenge myself. The answer is, according to [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

- Add padding, so that the resulting string is divisible with 3 Bytes.
- Set the padded 4bit values to 0 (depending on wether you do this before or after hexstring conversion, this is an actual 0 or a '0')
- In the resulting base64 string, the number of padded 4bit values is marked with the same amount of '=' at the end

The implementation of 0x41414141 seems not be a complete solution for the challenge, as the conversion from hexstring to binary is manually hardcoded. Besides, I don't understand why leading zeros should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution in C myself that handles any generic hex strings.
Note: it may not be 100% correct or not in best style as I am learning C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char b64[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
               'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
               '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'  };

char *bin_from_str(const char *str, const unsigned int size) {
  char *bin = calloc(size + 1, 1);

  for(int i = 0; i <= (int)size; ++i) {
    bin[i] = str[i];
    if (str[i] > 97) { // deal with lowercase
      bin[i] -= 87;
    } else if (str[i] > 65) { // deal with uppercase
      bin[i] -= 55;
    } else if (str[i] < 58) { // deal with nums
      bin[i] -= 48;
    }
  }

  return bin;
}

char *b64_from_hexstr(const char *hexstr, const unsigned int size) {
  char *bin = bin_from_str(hexstr, size);
  char *base64 = calloc((int)ceil(size * 4 / 6.0) + 1, 1);

  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < (int)size; i+=3, j+=2) {
    base64[j] = (bin[i] << 2) | ((i + 1 < (int)size) ? (bin[i + 1] >> 2) : 0);
    base64[j + 1] = ((bin[i + 1] & 0x3) << 4) | ((i + 2 < (int)size) ? bin[i + 2] : 0);
  }

  if (size % 3 == 1) { j--; } // remove trailing A's
  for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
    printf("%c", b64[(int)base64[i]]); // pretty print b64 string
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < (int)(size % 3); ++i) {
    printf("="); // add padding
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(bin);
  return base64;
}

int main(const int argc, const char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) { exit(1); }
  b64_from_hexstr(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

  return 0;
}
```

```bash
>> gcc 1-1.c && ./a.out 49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d

SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t
```