# how to convert a string of hex values into a base64 string

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, base64, sha1

I'm working on creating a websockets server, and I don't really know how to convert the hex values (which I got from **sha1** hashing) into a base64 string. I mean, the base64 string of:

```
"b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea"
```

is not:

```
"YjM3YTRmMmNjMDYyNGYxNjkwZjY0NjA2Y2YzODU5NDViMmJlYzRlYQ=="
```

it is:

```
"s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo="
```

But the library I use gives me the second one back when I give it the sha1 string above. Is that because the string above isn't considered as hex values?
These are the libraries I use:

> base64:
>   http://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/Base64/Encoding-and-decoding-base-64-with-cpp
>   sha1: http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha1-function

and it seems to me I've choosen the wrong ones. What can I use to get it working? I need to send some headers back to the client to establish connection, but I need to do these steps first.

Comment: Unicode characters?

Comment: The base 64 code encodes the characters of your string. It does not attempt to interpret it as a hexadecimal number. You may want to encode `{0xb3, 0x7a, 0x4f, ...}` instead.

Comment: can the library I use be applied to it? if not, what should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hexadecimal to base64 conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285118/hexadecimal-to-base64-conversion)

Comment: Get a SHA-1 function that returns raw bytes and then Base64 encode that.

Answer (score -2):

Different languages have different ways to dot it. Im c# you can use Convert.ToBase64String(hash); In php you can use base64_encode(hash).

Comment: The question is tagged C++. And even if the question was for C# or PHP, those functions won't solve the problem.